US Visa Appointment error: "Your personal details match a profile which already exists in our database"
I have a problem in the US Visa Scheduling Portal.
I completed adding a dependent (from create new dependent) and pressed submit button after entering their DS-160 confirmation number.
Later I found that there was some mistake in their DS-160, so I filled up a new DS-160 and removed that dependent as DS-160 confirmation number cannot be edited on an existing added dependent. But when I tried to add them back again using Create new Dependent button I couldn't do so. I got the below error:

Your personal details match a profile which already exists in our database. If you created this profile in the past and forgot the password, please use the 'Forgot your password?' function on the login screen. If this user name isn't familiar to you, please contact our helpline through the Provide Feedback option in the left menu or by sending an E-mail to our helpline. Please don't forget to attach the scanned copy of your passport's data page to your feedback message/E-mail.

Their passport number and other details are already present in the database and you are expected to add them using the UID. But you won't be having their UID since it is not displayed on any step while adding the dependent.
How can I get the UID?

You will have to call the embassy and then request the UID by giving the details for both the Applicant and dependents: Passport Number, Date of Birth, Relation to the Applicant.
You can then add them using UID and mention the new DS-160 confirmation number.
